# Hibernate - Map entity to existing row in table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible with JPA/Hibernate to have a table of persisted objects, and when creating an object externally, match it up with a persisted one such that the other attributes are populated?

For example, suppose I have a table that has the following information:

```
+--------+----------------+
| bazkey |    bazname     |
+--------+----------------+
|      1 | something      |
|      2 | someotherthing |
+--------+----------------+
```

This table is called `baztable` and contains persisted `Baz` objects that have the following definition:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "baztable")
public class Baz {
    @Id // plus some random key generator
    private int bazkey;

    @Column(name = "bazname")
    private String name;
}
```

I have another entity that maps down to the `baztable` via a `ManyToOne` relationship, meaning many of these entities can point to a single `Baz` object that's been persisted. Such an entity has the following definition:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "thingtable")
public class Thing {
    @Id // plus some random key generator
    private int thingkey;

    @Column(name = "thingname")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bazkey", referencedColumnName = "bazkey")
    private Baz baz;
}
```

Now without adding `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to the `@ManyToOne` annotation, a `Baz` object should be transient and will not be persisted. In my case, that's fine, because the `baztable` is populated elsewhere and I do not want a `Thing` entity to persist its child entities.

In order to populate the `baz` field of a `Thing` I could search the `baztable` by the `bazname` column for a given entity. But what I am wondering is if its possible to create the `Baz` entity explicitly, assigning it to the `baz` field and then when persisting the `Thing` entity, it automatically looks up the needed information for the `@JoinColumn`?

For example:

```
final Thing thing = new Thing();
thing.setName("thething");
thing.setBaz(new Baz("someotherthing"));
thingRepository.save(thing);

+----------+-----------+--------+
| thingkey | thingname | bazkey |
+----------+-----------+--------+
|        5 | thething  |      2 |
+----------+-----------+--------+
```

In the above, the `bazkey` column is populated with the `bazkey` corresponding to the `Baz` entity persisted with the name `someotherthing`, and subsequently its `bazkey` is used as the foreign key from the `thingtable`.

Comment: Your Thing->Baz reference requires the bazkey value to be set within Baz, and that is what identifies one Baz instance from others. If you want lookups by any other Baz property, you'll have to query for it yourself, as only you (and your app) can reliably know what to do if there is more than one instance found for the property lookup, or even which properties to query over. All JPA requires is the ID in the Baz entity if you aren't merging it though, so I'd suggest if you are going to pass around partial data, you use that instead of name properties (or have JPA use name as the PK and fks)

Comment: If you can't do that, I'd override the save logic in your thing repository to check the Baz reference and query for it if it isn't populated with an ID.